# why is django-dbbackup in .psql.bin format? Can I decode it?

Tags: django, postgresql

I just installed [django-dbbackup.](https://django-dbbackup.readthedocs.io/en/master/configuration.html). All working as per the doc (linked).

One thing slightly puzzles me. Why does it dump into a binary format which I don't know how to read? (`.psql.bin`). Is there a Postgres command to de-bin it?

I found by Googling, that it's possible to get a text dump by adding to settings.py

```
DBBACKUP_CONNECTOR_MAPPING = {  
 'django.db.backends.postgresql':
    'dbbackup.db.postgresql.PgDumpConnector',  
}
```

This is about 4x bigger as output, but after gzip'ping the file it's about 0.7x the size of the binary and after bzip2, about 0.5x

However, this appears to be undocumented, and I don't like using undocumented for backups! (same reason I want to be able to look at the file :-)

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it dump into a binary format which I don't know how to read? (.psql.bin).

You'll get a `.psql.bin` when using [`PgDumpBinaryConnector`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbbackup/blob/master/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py#L92-L98), which is [the default](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbbackup/blob/master/dbbackup/db/base.py#L21-L40) for Postgres databases.

> Is there a Postgres command to de-bin it?

The magic difference between `PgDumpConnector` and `PgDumpBinaryConnector` is the latter passes [`--format=custom`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbbackup/blob/790ec8bd297ef24cddfd2618d18d243abd15437e/dbbackup/db/postgresql.py#L108) to `pgdump` which is [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) as (emphasis mine)

> Output a custom-format archive **suitable for input into pg_restore**. Together with the directory output format, this is the most flexible output format in that it allows manual selection and reordering of archived items during restore. This format is also compressed by default.

IOW, I don't think there's an off-the-shelf de-binning command for it other than `pg_restore`ing and `pg_dump`ing back out as regular SQL, because you're not supposed to read it if you're not PostgreSQL.

[Of course, the format is de-facto documented in the source for `pg_dump`...](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/eb5ad4ff05fd382ac98cab60b82f7fd6ce4cfeb8/src/bin/pg_dump/pg_backup_custom.c)